# Open a web page in the Apple Watch simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, watchkit, apple-watch

watchOS 5 allows to open a web page from Mail or Messages, but these apps are not present in the Simulator.

I tried using `xcrun simctl openurl <device> <URL>`, which works with an iPhone simulator, but with a Watch returns an error:

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code=-10814):
The operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)
```

[This error means](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1469236-anonymous/klsapplicationnotfounderr) “No application in the Launch Services database matches the input criteria.”

Is there a way to open a web page in an Apple Watch simulator?

Comment: My solution under another similar question works with the simulator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74951547/3151675

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible, [according to WebKit’s Wenson Hsieh](https://twitter.com/wensonhsieh/status/1008717148913451008).