# How can I open URLs in watchOS?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

Can a standalone Apple Watch app open a URL like we can in iOS:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

I want to display a message about an update when a new app is published. I want the user to go the URL for the update. Is there any good way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you're using SwiftUI or not, but the `Link` View is shown in the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link) as available for watchOS. However using it in practice only prompts the user to open the link on their iPhone. As a standalone app since Safari is not available on watchOS you might want to consider other options to alert your user of an update.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello, World!")
        Link("Apple.com", destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!)
    }
}
}
```

[image: Apple Watch]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I had checked your code on my watch. I thought can solve it because can open url on message App. But I understood it seems like hard to solve it.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to open a link on the watch? I want to add a link to show an app's privacy policy from its website but `Link` is not working

Answer (score 4):

The following answer works in watchOS 6.2 and above. It initiates a web authentication session, which opens a web view, similar to WKWebView on iOS. You can even swipe from the left to go back.

Keep in mind that it doesn't save cookies, so, for example, if you log in to a website and close it, you have to log in again when you open it back up.

```
import AuthenticationServices
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap me") {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com") else {
                return
            }

            // Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/rcn2h7/comment/hnwr8do/
            let session = ASWebAuthenticationSession(
                url: url,
                callbackURLScheme: nil
            ) { _, _ in

            }

            // Makes the "Watch App Wants To Use example.com to Sign In" popup not show up
            session.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true

            session.start()
        }
    }
}
```